# How to know if ListView finished rendering?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Let's say I have the following block of code:

```
  componentWillMount() {
      fetch('API_LINK', {
          method: "GET"
      })
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState(datasource: ds.cloneWithRows(data)))
      .done()
  }

  _renderRow(rowID){
      return(
          <Text>{rowID.title}</Text>
      )
  }

  render() {
      return(
           //....
      )
  }
```

Is there some kind of event that can help me know exactly when the ListView data finished rendering and got drawn into the app?

Example:

```
<ListView
    dataSource={this.state.datasource}
    renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}
    onRenderFinish={() => console.log("Finished loading!")}
/>
```

Comment: ListView will not render all the items at once. It renders the items which are needed to be displayed. Just curious, Why do you need callback like 'onRenderFinish'? What are you trying to achieve with this callback?

Comment: Have you checked out the `onEndReached` method? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#onendreached